Is implication associative in intuitionistic propositional calculus?
Let there be a collection of elements called "notions". From these notions we can combine the elements of a selection in order to form new "notions". We can combine them in three ways: "and", "or", and "implies", each of which is a binary (2-input) function Notion x Notion -> Notion. For example, the "and"-combination of notion 1 and notion 2 can be written and(notion 1, notion 2), or notion 1 and notion 2; this is to be regarded as a notion in its own right. The same is true for the other operations. A notion can be evaluated to "true" or "false"; each of the previously mentioned operations has a particular relationship to the truth-values of the notions it's constituted of, summarized in these standard truth tables:



X
Y
and(X, Y)




false
false
false


false
true
false


true
false
false


true
true
true






X
Y
or(X, Y)




false
false
false


false
true
true


true
false
true


true
true
true






X
Y
implies(X, Y)




false
false
true


false
true
true


true
false
false


true
true
true



From these operations one can construct an infinitude of notions, such as implies(and(X, Y), implies(Y, Z)) and or(and(or(Z,Y), W), X); such expressions are also called formulae. However, due to the way the operations act on truth-values, notions can be collected into equivalence classes based on if they have the same truth-values. Let "verum" be the name of the equivalence class of any notion that is always true, regardless of the truthhood of any of its constituent notions; for example, if "A implies A" were taken to be true whether or not A itself is true, then notion "A implies A" lies in the equivalence class verum. "Falsum" is the corresponding idea for notions that are always false.
We will add structure to this system of operations with an entailment relation, of the form "Notion 1 entails Notion 2". The entailment relation allows us to define logical scenarios, with the use of axioms; it allows us to relate the operations to one another, and to relate specific notions to one another as well. The presentation of some entailment assertions, called sequents, can always be thought of as hypothetical; i.e., the collection of assertions:

Notion 1 entails Notion 2.
Notion 3 entails Notion 1 and Notion 2.
Notion 4 entails Notion 1 implies Notion 3.

is not making claims about "the world", but about "a world": some scenario in which it is taken to be true. If two notions entail one another, we can say they are equal, and write "Notion 1 = Notion 2".
We are still missing something essential: the ability to make derivations from such assertions. Our choice of "deduction rules" will establish what kind of logic we are using. For example, we can say:

If in any scenario, a notion of the form "Notion 1 and Notion 2" is entailed; then one can deduce that Notion 1 is also entailed, in that scenario.
And if in any scenario, a notion of the form "Notion 1 and Notion 2" is entailed; then one can deduce that Notion 2 is also entailed, in that scenario.
And if in any scenario, both a notion 1 is entailed, and a notion 2 is entailed (i.e., separately), then the notion "Notion 1 and Notion 2" is also entailed.

The first two rules are examples of elimination rules, because they permit one to eliminate an operation - "and" - and deduce a notion that is without that operation. The third rule is an example of an introduction rule, because it permits one to create a notion using that specific operation - "and" - from notions where it was absent.
In addition to the rules of "and" above, these will be the other rules of our system:

If for any notions, Notion 1 or Notion 2 entails something, then it follows that Notion 1 entails that same something.
If for any notions, Notion 1 or Notion 2 entails something, then it the case that Notion 2 also entails that same something.
If for any notions, it is the case that a Notion 1 entails something, and it is the case that a Notion 2 entails something, then it also is the case that Notion 1 or Notion 2 entails that same something.
If for any notions, Notion 1 and Notion 2 entail some Notion 3, then it is the case that Notion 1 entails Notion 2 implies Notion 3.
If for any notions, Notion 1 entails Notion 2 implies Notion 3, then it is the case that Notion 1 and Notion 2 entails Notion 3

I just tried to define intuitionistic propositional logic in my own words, and from this point onwards am much more new and unfamiliar to this topic.
My question is about the implication operation. I think there will be some interesting things to be realized, given not just how it is defined relative to the and operation, but also given the consideration for why this is apparently not a deduction rule in classical propositional logic. (In classic propositional logic, there are no deduction rules for working with a sequent of the form "A and B entails C".)
My first question is: in this logic, is implication associative? Does (p -> q) -> r = p -> (q -> r)?
A proof of this would consist in deriving the sequent "p -> (q -> r) entails (p -> q) -> r", and the sequent "(p -> q) -> r entails p -> (q -> r)", from the above deduction rules (plus identity and modus ponens, which I forgot to include.)

Intuitionistic logic, under conventional definitions (Brower interpretation), is a logic which doesn't assume the Law of the Excluded Middle. However, at the very start, you posit that every "notion" must be either true or false, contradicting this. Perhaps you are simply working under a different conception of intuitionism, but I would review yourself to make sure. I may also be misinterpreting your writing.

Implication is not associative in intuitionistic logic. You cannot define intuitionistic connectives using truth tables. Your rules for 'or' are not correct. You will also need rules for negation and/or falsum, because those are where intuitionistic logic differs from classical.

You do not want implication to be associative in any logic. Indeed, p → (p → p) is a tautology because p → p is already a tautology in any reasonable logic, but if (p → p) → p was also a tautology then you could derive any p whatsoever.
